# How do I make this dice game run in a simulation 10,000 times using python?

Tags: python

I'm doing a homework assignment. I can't seem to find a solution on how to make the dice roll 10,000 times plus create a variable that updates everytime you win some money when you roll the dice correctly. I have some instructions on the homework below can anyone shed some light on me?

The game is played as follows: roll a six sided die.
If you roll a 1, 2 or a 3, the game is over.
If you roll a 4, 5, or 6, you win that many dollars ($4, $5, or $6), and then roll again.
With each additional roll, you have the chance to win more money, or you might roll a game-ending 1, 2, or 3, at which time the game is over and you keep whatever winnings you have accumulated.

Use the randint function from Python's Random module to get a die roll result
(see functions for integers).

Run 10,000 simulations of the game (Monte Carlo method).
Print the average amount won and the largest amount won.

Just as a thought experiment, would you pay $3 for a chance to play this game?

Example Output:

Average amount won = x.xx
Max amount won = xx

```
import random

class diceGame:

    def __init__(self,dice):
        self.dice = dice

    def gameOutCome(self):

            askUser = str(input("Roll to play the game? Y/N: "))
            while True:
                if askUser == 'y':
                    print(self.dice)
                    if self.dice == 1:
                        print("Sorry, Try Again!")
                    elif self.dice == 2:
                        print("Sorry, Try Again!")
                    elif self.dice == 3:
                        print("Sorry, Try Again!")
                    elif self.dice == 4:
                        print("You win $4")
                    elif self.dice == 5:
                        print("You win $5")
                    elif self.dice == 6:
                        print("You win $6")

                askUser = str(input("Roll to play the game? Y/N: "))









x = random.randint(1,6)
dd = diceGame(x)
dd.gameOutCome()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11082165).

Comment: Don't ask for input in a simulation.  Do you want to answer the questions 10,000 times?  Write a function that plays the game once and call the function 10,000 times using a for loop, e.g. `for sim in range(10000):`.

Comment: What is the standard method for repetition in Python, and many other programming languages?

Comment: @MarkTolonen The for loop is working but the dice is not updating. why is that happening i thought in the instance with random.randint in would update all the time. why is my dice not updating this is why i am stuck?

Comment: Only if you call `random.randint()` again.  Edit your question and show your code attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow. Since this is your homework, I don't think it is appropriate to post an entire solution here.

However I do think some pointers in the right direction might be helpful:

1) You are running the simulation 10000 times. Each roll requires 2 user inputs. So in order to finish the simulation you need at least 20000 user inputs... Yeah that will be tiresome ;) .... So lets cut the user input - just write a function that executes the game until the game is finished. Once you have a function that executes one game, how can you execute it multiple times?

2) Think of each roll having two possible outcomes - continue the game or not. What des it mean to continue? What condition has to be fullfilled for the game to end?

3) Once the game has ended, what do you need to do with the money?

4) You can use the sum and max functions to calculate the average and the maximum win.

```
import random

def play_game():
    #The function that executes the game - you have to write that on your own
    pass

wins = [play_game() for i in range(0,10000)]
win_average = sum(wins)/10000.0
max_win = max(wins)
```